# ScriptResource.axd path is too long

Tags: c#, asp.net, path, io, scriptresource.axd

here is my problem.

I develop web applications, and I use IIS to host them.

I also used the module ARR (application request routing) as a proxy for my server farm. The problem is the ARR cache the pages on disk. I have ScriptResource  cached in the arr cache disk, and when I try to delete the access path is too long.

Is there a way to shorten the name of the script resources?

thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you use ASP.NET 4.0 you can use CDN version of scripts and get additional benefits. Just set EnableCdn property of your script manager to true and your script links will look like this :

```
<script src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/4.0/1/WebForms.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/4.0/1/MicrosoftAjax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/4.0/1/MicrosoftAjaxWebForms.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: unfortunatly AFAIK just partial, you can use some scripts from CDN but not all of them, look at http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETAjaxScriptCombiningAndMovingScriptResourceaxdsToStaticScripts.aspx